# binding to Array.includes [javascript]

Tags: javascript, bind

I'm trouble with using this in find if any element in array2 exists in array1:

```
array2 = [].includes.bind([1,2,3]);
array2(1);   // returns true
array2(9);   // returns false

[5,6,7,8,9].some(array2);        // returns false  GOOD
[3,6,7,8,9].some(array2);        // returns true   GOOD
[6,7,8,9,3].some(array2);        // returns false  OOPS!

[6,7,8,9,3].some(function(i){return array2(i)});  //returns true
```

Obviously I know one solution to the problem, but I want to know why the `[...].some(array2)` doesn't work completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[6,7,8,9,3].some(array2)` doesn't work because `Array.prototype.some` calls check function with 3 arguments: value, index, entire array while `Array.prototype.includes` takes [2 arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Where the second argument is starting index to search from.

> arr.includes(searchElement, fromIndex)

So every next call asks if your first array includes given value starting the given index.

Comment: @chsdk I really can't see how your examples prove me wrong. `[8,7,3,8,9].some(array2)` is true because `[1,2,3].includes(3, 2)` is true. And `[8,7,1,8,9].some(array2)` is false because `[1,2,3].includes(1, 2)` is false

Comment: "This isn't the case here because if we run these tests"? What did you mean by "this"?